# UIPickerView with custom views broken in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

I have an app with a UIPickerView.  I am returning a custom view with the method

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

It looked fine in iOS 6.  In iOS 7, not so much -- screen shot below.

Notice that in the cells that don't have focus, the second and third columns overlap.  The central row is correct.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: That is strange. I have created one for test it. But everything is ok. Example http://snipt.org/BaIi0/Default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that for a strange reason, if the width of any column is higher than 1/3 of the picker view's width the layout breaks. So if you have a 320 pixel wide picker view 106 or less is working, but 107 or higher is wrong, regardless if you have 2,3,4 ... components. Really strange.

Comment: The only workaround I see so far is to increase the width of the first component, and decrease the width of the others on iOS 7.

Comment: Thanks! Still happens nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

As imihaly said in his earlier post it looks like this only happens if the widthForComponent value for the LAST component is more than 106 pixels. The other components can return a value over 106 and it will look fine. Also, if you return a view that's smaller in width than the value returned by widthForComponent it will center the view, but it will be offset to the left by about 10 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but I was displaying simple numbers instead.  See [my similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825688/ios7-uipickerview-non-selected-row-curvature-modification-multiple-components).  Short answer is that I had to break up the components into different UIPickerViews.

Answer (score 0):

As @imihaly mentioned, There is only one solutions that I come up with to increase a width of picker view which is add into view.

I have created a demo like https://github.com/Dharmesh-shah2412/demoPickerView